# How to self-register a standalone desktop C# WPF app (distributed as an exe) for local toast notifications?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

We have a desktop Windows app (written in WFP/C#) that we distribute as a single .exe file with no installer (it bundles all its dependencies via a Fody/Costura plugin).

We would like to integrate a local Action Center toast functionality where the app  can display a toast and respond to it when it's clicked.

Displaying the toast is straightforward and can be done by using the  Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications nuget package. However, in order to actually receive proper notifications when the toast is clicked in the Action Center (as opposed to the balloon tip) we need to register with notification platform.

The guide on how to do this seems to be focused on apps with an installer (e.g. Wix): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop?fbclid=IwAR2AoHRKI88VNGRG-pTUytwhkMuovWT4bEr0RoXEayWpWsoGlghtZeq4Mo4#step-4-register-with-notification-platform

The specific task we're trying to achieve is, from the documentation:

> If you're using classic Win32 (or if you support both), you have to declare your Application User Model ID (AUMID) and toast activator CLSID (the GUID from step #3) on your app's shortcut in Start.

How can we do it without writing an installer? We would like our app to do this registration on first run.

**Note:** the app already has provisions for elevating itself through UAC if needed by restarting itself in Administrator context.

Additional references: [WPF native windows 10 toasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441202/wpf-native-windows-10-toasts)

[**Update**]

I managed to follow the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop
and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/enable-desktop-toast-with-appusermodelid to put together what should have been a working solution, but in the end, clicking on toasts in the Action Center does not trigger OnActivated() in my NotificationActivatior.

Salient points:

1. Sending notification

   ```
   var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
   DesktopNotificationManagerCompat.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
   ```
2. Registration:

   ```
   string shortcutPath = Path.Combine(
     Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs),
     "Toasty.lnk");

   DesktopNotificationManagerCompat.RegisterAumidAndComServer
     <MyNotificationActivator>(AppName);

   DesktopNotificationManagerCompat.RegisterActivator
     <MyNotificationActivator>();

   if (!File.Exists(shortcutPath))
   {
     ShortcutManager.RegisterAppForNotifications(
       shortcutPath,
       Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
       null,
       AppName,
       ActivationId);
    }
   ```
3. Creating a shortcut

```
    public static void RegisterAppForNotifications(
      string shortcutPath,
      string appExecutablePath,
      string arguments,
      string appName,
      string activatorId)
    {
      var shellLinkClass = new ShellLinkCoClass();
      IShellLinkW shellLink = (IShellLinkW)shellLinkClass;
      shellLink.SetPath(appExecutablePath);
    
      IPropertyStore propertyStore = (IPropertyStore)shellLinkClass;
      IPersistFile persistFile = (IPersistFile)shellLinkClass;
    
      if (arguments != null)
      {
        shellLink.SetArguments(arguments);
      }
            
      // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-appusermodel-id
      propertyStore.SetValue(
          new PropertyKey("9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3", 5),
          new PROPVARIANT(appName));
    
       // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-appusermodel-toastactivatorclsid
       propertyStore.SetValue(
         new PropertyKey("9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3", 26),
         new PROPVARIANT(new Guid(activatorId)));
       propertyStore.Commit();
    
       persistFile.Save(shortcutPath, true);
    }
```

[**Update**]

Finally got it to work - not sure what was wrong before, but the final version seems to be okay. Full code: https://gist.github.com/davidair/c4ea207bf6eece4ef08b97ab29a3036f

Comment: Found the article that gives the C++ code to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/enable-desktop-toast-with-appusermodelid. Next step - port it to C#.

Comment: Updated my question with the implementation, afterwards made sure SetValue is using PROPVARIANT, not object (https://github.com/BigBadOwl/SolidEdge.Community.Reader/blob/master/src/SolidEdge.Community.Reader/Native/Structures.cs#L123) and made sure the properties persist correctly. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem with my project now.

Managed to find this repository - https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-interactive-notifications

Here's C++ implementation for installing shortcut (InteractiveNotifications file, InstallShortcut method). I guess the problem is how we set the value to PropertyStore, string GUID is not suitable for some reason. Still, I wasn't able to solve the problem for now.

UPDATED: Finally, was able to install shortcut from code! Check my example at Github. https://github.com/romayavorskyi/WpfNotificationTest (still a lot of hardcode, but it should give you the general idea). And you were right, shortcut path matters. It seems shortcut should be in the ProgramData folder for correct work.

Comment: Thank you for sharing - I think I figured out at least the PropertyStore part. Is your project in C++ or C#? The key is using PROVARIANT (see my latest comment) with CLSID type, I have not updated my gist yet but I can do it shortly.

I was also given a pointer of using SysInternal Process Monitor to actually see what Action Center does to troubleshoot (apparently another issue is where the lnk files are created).

Comment: Alright, I've updated my gist with the PROPVARIANT version - I've tested that the shortcut now has correct entries for both properties.

Comment: Thanks for your implementation! It sets correct properties, still can't catch the activation event for some reason. I'll try to parse Wix shortcut properties and figure out where's the difference.

Comment: Managed to register the shortcut from code, please, check the answer update

Comment: Thank you Roman, I've noticed you are using a global folder that required admin rights, but this should work too: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs) (the nice thing about using Programs is that it doesn't force the app to load on startup).

Comment: Additionally, DesktopNotificationManagerCompat.cs is no longer needed - it's now part of  the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications assembly